# Seems impossible for me to get rid of this spam from Gmail

Tags: gmail

Every day, I get at least 6-12 emails that have a very common pattern, but there doesn't appear to be any possible search syntax I can use to create rules to block these emails.

For example:

[image]

All of these spam emails are sending emails to <random_name><random_number>@aol.com. These are obviously not my email addresses and I don't use AOL. From my knowledge, there's no regex that I can use to block all emails to Alton*@aol.com. The source email address is always random, and the "to" addresses are always some variation of Alton*@aol.com

The other thing that I noticed is that I can clearly see this buried somewhere in the HTML of the email contents:

[image]

Again, there's no way for me to search the source email (at least to my knowledge). For example, searching for `"organising your visa"` returns absolutely nothing, although these words are clearly in the body of the emails that I'm looking for.

The number of these emails are just ramping up more and more every month, and I find myself having to spend several moments every morning to clear these out, especially if I've missed a day or two.

Obviously, it's not the biggest deal in the world, but like most people, I'm trying to reduce clutter in my inbox.

Is there anything I'm missing here on how to automatically handle this from Gmail? It seems that I'm going to have to invest in a third-party app and sign in with Gmail there (not something I'd want to do for obvious security reasons).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have received many spam emails that are similar in the past, and sometimes wonder how they get through Gmail's sophisticated filters.

My best advice is to help gmail detect this junk (for you, but also helps many others). You can report the email as spam by checking the checkbox next to the email then clicking 'Report Spam':

[image]

This may not prevent these emails arriving *immediately*, but it will definitely help the algorithms a lot to detect them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use AOL then you can simply set up a filter to delete any emails addressed to @aol.com.

[image]

Comment: The problem though is if someone sends me a legitimate email with someone's AOL email address copied, that email will get deleted based on this rule.